# Ошибка при SOAP-запросе из PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

**Запрос выглядит так:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <Buy xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <perf>
   <param1>1111</param1>
   <param2>2222</param2>
  </perf>
 </Buy>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

**Запрос делаю через SoapClient:**

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://0.0.0.0:8080/Service1.asmx?wsdl",
 array(
  'trace' => true,
  'exceptions'=>true
 ));
```

**getTypes и getFunctions отрабатывают корректно.**

```
$types = $client->__getTypes();
$functions = $client->__getFunctions ();
```

**Создаю объект и пытаюсь увидеть результат:**

```
$std = new stdClass();
$std->param1 = '1111';
$std->param2 = '2222';

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // отключаем кэширование WSDL 

$result = $client->Buy( array('perf' => $std ) );
var_dump($result); exit;
```

**В результате получаю SoapFault:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /var/www/index.php:86 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('Buy', Array) #2 /var/www/index.php(86): SoapClient->Buy(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/index.php on line 86
```

**В логах apache следующее:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /var/www/index.php:86\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://0.0.0...', 'http://tempuri....', 1, 0)\n#1 /var/www/index.php(86): SoapClient->__call('Buy', Array)\n#2 /var/www/index.php(86): SoapClient->Buy(Array)\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/index.php on line 86
```

***Подскажите***, кто знает, может проблема в том как я объект с данными собираю? Или в том, как я параметры в запрос вставляю?

Comment: Скачайте этот wsdl себе и посмотрите на какой адрес там предполагается подключаться.

Comment: Судя по ошибке проблема в том, что клиент не может подключиться к серверу по порту 8080, т.е. либо неправильный адрес сервер, либо доступ к нему заблокирован.

Comment: @АлексейШмелёв, до сервера нормально стучится. Когда выполняю getFunctions или getTypes, я получаю с сервера ожидаемый результат. Но когда делаю конкретный запрос к функции - такая ошибка

Comment: @PavelMayorov, адрес для запроса корректный

Comment: @ОлегПотемкин корректный - это какой? Я вот не могу понять как он у вас вообще на 0.0.0.0 подключается...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, 0.0.0.0 это localhost, как и 127.0.0.1

Comment: @ОлегПотемкин а сам метод `Buy` как-то тестировался, он работает? Может быть проблема в нём?

Comment: Всё-таки похоже сервер ожидает другую структуру xml в запросе, а когда получает не то - падает. Потестируйте через [soapui](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html), в нём строится пример xml-запроса на основе wsdl.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 - это я затер реальный IP нулями) Про soapui спасибо - сейчас попробую. Отдельно метод Buy не тестировался, т.к. серверная часть мне "неподвластна", она за клиентом, у меня доступов нет

Comment: А кстати, возможно ли увидеть структуру сформированного xml-запроса? Потому что я вижу в логах апаче, что xml формируется `SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://0.0.0.`

Comment: А вот как данный xml вывести на экран или в логи записать?

Comment: @ОлегПотемкин Можно: $client->__getLastRequest() и $client->__getLastRequestHeaders()